# How do I create a playlist from multiple video IDs on youtube?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I have a multitude of video IDs (200+) and I would like to create a youtube playlist using all of the video IDs. I tried solutions from here:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120451/how-to-create-a-playlist-form-a-list-of-links-not-from-bookmarks

None of those solutions worked, and most of them had a 50 video limit. The python code given only had the first video in it, and none of the other videos. The first method didn't work either, and  the excel sheet, when copied, completely broke for me.

Is there any way for me to add these videos to a playlist, which is not manual? EG. Using a playlist creator or a program / api? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source / Credits: [Create a YouTube Playlist Without an Account With This URL Trick](https://lifehacker.com/create-a-youtube-playlist-without-an-account-with-this-1688862486)

---

By following this structure, you can create an untitled playlist:

> `http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4`

This is an example I created:

> `http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=nWyetldx4PU,gvubjVKOMuc,M3emJNkMmnA,QL2ohdMRck0,irTjCnHmU-E`

After pasting the previous URL in the browser, the URL changed to: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWyetldx4PU&list=TLGGyc5oTGfqXdswNjEwMjAyMA`

Comment: Could it be that `TL`'s meaning is *temporary list*; if this is true, then one natural question arise: for how long a time does YouTube retain this temporary playlist alive (i.e. valid)?

Comment: Interesting facts: (1) each time I accessed the URL above `http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=nWyetldx4PU,gvubjVKOMuc,M3emJNkMmnA,QL2ohdMRck0,irTjCnHmU-E`, the YouTube's Web UI responded with the same playlist URL as shown above; thus the backend does not create new temporary playlists each time one accesses the same list of video IDs.

Comment: (2) the [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) API endpoint doesn't return any [`Playlists resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource) when queried with `id=TLGGyc5oTGfqXdswNjEwMjAyMA` (the response contains an empty `items` array: `"items":[]`).

Comment: @stvar I guess the `TLGGyc5oTGfqXdswNjEwMjAyMA` contains the *encoded/obfuscated* URLs used in the link. I'm looking for documentation about it, but, I don't think there is any available.

Comment: Until now I did not came across any such playlist (`TL...`), neither in the official docs, nor anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have the URLs of videos, get the ids of the videos with Regular expression.
2. then, create a playlist with the help of @Mauricio Arias Olave's answer.
   or you can follow my video too https://youtu.be/_gaVUYfWb6g
3. then with this below Js code you can convert the playlist to a permanent playlist in your youtube account. It simply adds those videos to the first available playlist. `els2[1].click();` you can change the number in this line to select a different playlist.
   you will have to run this code in the browser console.

this will work until youtube changes their HTML lol.

```
(function myLoop(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
    letters[i].click();
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(".style-scope.ytd-menu-service-item-renderer");
    console.log(els);
    if(els.length){
        els[6].click();
        var els2 =  document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox-height.style-scope.ytd-playlist-add-to-option-renderer");
        if(els2.length){
            els2[1].click();
             console.log("saved in playlist");
        }
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].click();
    if (--i) myLoop(i);   //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
  }, 3000)
})(letters.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated working version (2024) of @arif-khan script

In the playlist page, assuming the playlist you want to copy to is the newest one

```
var three_dots_menus = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-trigger.style-scope.ytd-menu-renderer")).slice(1);
for (let index = 0; index < three_dots_menus.length; index++) {
    console.log(index)
    var menu = three_dots_menus[index];
    menu.click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 700));
    var sub_menu = document.querySelectorAll(".style-scope.ytd-menu-service-item-renderer");
    sub_menu[8].click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 700));
    document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox-height.style-scope.ytd-playlist-add-to-option-renderer")[1].click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 700));
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 700));
}
```

you might need to play with the timeouts