# How do I use youtube api to generate playlist from IDs in bash?

Tags: url, youtube, youtube-dl, playlist

My goal is to write a bash script that will extract multiple ID's from playlists in a script then dump them to a text file sort them and remove any duplicates that keep adding to the same text file then use the contents to generate playlists from the text file

e.g I have 800 songs listed in a text file and I do something like `sort -R  /tmp/songs.txt | head -n50` to list 50 songs randomly then pipe to a playlist URL.

I am OK with how to extract the video IDs from playlists save them and then randomly generate the songs I want, but I need help in how to create a URL that will generate the playlist on YouTube

I found this [How do I create a playlist from multiple video IDs on youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891076/how-do-i-create-a-playlist-from-multiple-video-ids-on-youtube) it accomplishes almost what I want however the playlist generated is unlisted and untitled is there a way I can generate playlists with titles and be listed?

EDIT: I just found this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2Cstatus%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22snippet%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A%22New%20playlist%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22New%20playlist%20description%22%7D%2C%22status%22%3A%7B%22privacyStatus%22%3A%22private%22%7D%7D%7D which is sort of on the right track but I can't make sense of it any help would be appreciated it does show enough info to prove you can create a list using API and token IDs to make public playlists for your channel which is exactly what I want I just need help making sense of it.

Comment: " in how to parse a URL that will generate the playlist on youtube" -> I'm confused. Parse basically mean to read. Do you rather want to _create_ an URL that, when accessed, will create a playlist?

Comment: Yes sorry that is what I meant I will edit my post thanks

Comment: How do I bump this no one has answered?